# Ubuntu "No root file system defined" after Wubi install of 11.04 on Windows XP

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, partitioning

I'm unable to fully boot into Ubuntu 11.04 on a system that dual boots XP.  XP is working and was installed first.  Details below:

After having problems upgrading a previously working but old Ubuntu v9.10 installation I decided the easiest thing to do was probably just uninstall Ubuntu and do a fresh install of the latest version.

Here's what I did:

1. Uninstall Ubuntu from the Add / Remove programs in Windows XP.
2. Remove the C:\wubildr.mbr = "Ubuntu" line from the boot.ini.
3. Reboot Windows XP and confirm the old Ubuntu files are gone and Windows has reclaimed the file space.
4. Download and install the latest Ubuntu Windows installer (wubi.exe).
5. Install Ubuntu using wubi to the same disk as last time, though this time I allocated 10 GB instead of 30 GB.
6. The install seemed to go well and I was prompted to reboot to finish installing.
7. Selected Ubuntu at the beginning of the boot and Ubuntu seemed to be completing the install.

That's when I received the following error:

> Verifying the installation configuration No root file system defined.
>   Please correct this from the partitioning menu

I'm unable to get beyond this error. Every time I click "Ok" the error is displayed again.

Any suggestions of how to troubleshoot this problem are greatly appreciated.

I have run boot_info_script.sh by booting Ubuntu from a Live CD.  Would it be helpful if I pasted the result here?  Is there a particular section of the results I should post?

Comment: Why don't you install it from the Live CD? That's how it always worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

As @mailq said, make a Live CD/DVD/USB to boot off of. You can download [this](http://unetbootin.github.io/) application to download the image and install it to your live object. In order to boot off of the live object. Restart your computer, but before Windows starts loading, press <kbd>F2</kbd> and set the option "F12 Boot Menu" to Yes/True. After you do this press <kbd>F10</kbd> or go to the tab marked "Exit" and select "Save and exit". Finally, press <kbd>F12</kbd> and choose your live object ("USB HDD" for USB or "USB CDROM" for CD-ROM).

Comment: Remember to back up your files before anything!!! You could potentially wipe your hard drive and lose **ALL** of your files!